# ElasticSearch Aggregate vs Count api

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to compute some simple statistic over log Event like download with elasticSearch. I am wondering what is the difference between the Count API and Bucket Aggregate Filter combine with Value Count aggregate ? Is there any benefit of using aggregate over the count api ?

Comment: Benefit as in speed performance?

Comment: There might be something i don't see, i am asking because it seem to be redudant.

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish the same thing. In your case it might seems redundant, but maybe for some other use case, the count API is not useful.